# XAMPP PHP PDO dblib connects without PHP extensions ( without dblib.dll file )

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, xampp

My colleague has an application that connects to MS SQL server using dblib driver:

```
$p = new PDO('dblib:...');
```

I cannot run this application on my windows env. because it's using dblib to connect. My friend on the other side can on his windows xampp.

Of course on my laptop where I got linux installed it works just as it should.

Curious thing is that xampp does not have dblib driver but its dsn for PDO somehow works. How is that, is there a driver that emulates its behaviour somehow?

Comment: It always helps to see real code rather than vague textual descriptions of it (connects to MS SQL Server? how?).

Comment: But it does not involve any code but only PDO drivers <?php $p = new PDO('dblib:...'); thats pretty much all there is to it. It connects on a Windows Xampp machine without dblib.dll php extension enabled ( or even existing )

Comment: Well, don't touch it, don't ask too many question, be glad it works.